# 401 error on Twitter post requests

Tags: php, laravel, twitter, twitter-oauth, guzzle

I can't get post requests to the twitter api to work. Login & GET requests seem to work fine though. I always get this reponse:

```
401 Authorization Required response:
{"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}
```

I'm using Laravel 5.3, Guzzle 6.3 and Guzzle/oauth-subscriber 0.3. Here's my code:

```
$stack = HandlerStack::create();

$middleware = new Oauth1([
    'consumer_key'    => env('TWITTER_CLIENT_ID'),
    'consumer_secret' => env('TWITTER_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    'token'           => env('TWITTER_TOKEN'),
    'token_secret'    => env('TWITTER_TOKEN_SECRET')
]);

$stack->push($middleware);

$client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/',
    'handler' => $stack
]);

$res = $client->post(
  'account/update_profile_image.json?image=' . $avatar,
  [
    'auth' => 'oauth',
  ]
);
```

My app settings in Twitters' dev page is set to read & write, so that isn't the problem. Regenerated the keys once, no dice. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, turns out you have to write the post request like this:

```
$client->request(
      'POST', 
      'account/update_profile_image.json',
      [ 
      'multipart' => 
      [
        [
            'name'     => $name,
            'contents' => fopen($path), 'r'),
            'filename' => $fileName
        ],
      ], 
      'auth' => 'oauth', 
      //'debug' => true, 
      ]
    );
```